# How to update foreign keys in one table when new record is added in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have two tables:

```
Table A (id int pk, value nvarchar(10), version nvarchar(5))

Table B (id2 int pk, value2 nvarchar(20), TableAID int fk(tableA.id), version nvarchar(5))
```

Sample data are:

```
Table A
-------
id | value | version
1    a       1
2    b       1      

Table B
-------
id | value | TableAID | version
1    c       1             1
2    d       1             1
```

Now if i insert new record with new version in table A, i'm getting following:

```
Table A
-------
id | value | version
1    null    1
2    b       1
3    a       2
```

And Table B should look like this:

```
Table B
-------
id | value | TableAID | version
1    c       3             1
2    d       3             1
```

(Foreign key field have to change).

How to accomplish that???? I'm filling data and version with cursors.

**UPDATE!**

The thing is that I have to insert new row for every new version of data in Table A. I'm not allowed to delete old versions, and I have to make them stay as they are. The new versions are inserted as new data but the old version of same data change their value to null.

If I insert new version of data in Table A I that get also a new ID for that value. So I have to update the Table B with that new ID.

Comment: so if you add a record in A with an already existing value, than you want to value of the record where it already exists to update its value to null ?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on what you are trying to achieve?  I suspect your table design would need to change, but without background info it is hard to advise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this by using foreign key constraints.
I would rather suggest you to use an Insert trigger on table A.
The update statement in the insert trigger would look like below:

```
UPDATE B
SET B.TableAID = I.ID
FROM B 
INNER JOIN A
 ON A.ID = B.TableAID
INNER JOIN INSERTED I
 ON I.VALUE = A.VALUE
```